# SQL Server : 2 table inner join. I need to add a 3rd join to get one column of data

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

This is the query I am currently using.

```
SELECT title1, 
    [precinct percent] AS [PrecinctPercent], 
    leader, 
    [leader percent] AS [LeaderPercent], 
    Winner, 
    WinningVotes, 
    leader2, 
    [leader2 percent] AS [Leader2Percent], 
    Loser, 
    LosingVotes 
    FROM dbo.[RACE]  r inner join
     (select rc.[race number],
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then [candidate num] end) as Winner,
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then Votes end) as WinningVotes,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then [candidate num] end) as Loser,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then Votes end) as LosingVotes
      from (select rc.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by rc.[race number] order by votes desc) as seqnum
            from dbo.[RACE CANDIDATES] rc
           ) rc
      group by rc.[race number]
     ) rc
     on r.[race number] = rc.[race number]
     FOR XML PATH ('WQAD'), ROOT('root')
```

This outputs the data I need. It puts 2 race candidates into one single rowset. candidate 1 being winner and candidate2 being loser. The winning and losing votes follow each candidate correctly.

What I am now trying to do, is retrieve the `PARTY` value from a table named `CANDIDATE`. I am not exactly sure on how to write the query to just include a reference to this third table, `CANDIDATE`. Also, I am trying to get the party value (D or B) to follow each candidate, Such as Winner, WinnerVotes, WinnerParty..Loser, LoserVotes, LoserParty...something like that.

Here is the schema of the 3 tables --below

```
USE [leader]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[RACE CANDIDATES]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RACE CANDIDATES](
    [race number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [candidate num] [int] NOT NULL,
    [votes] [int] NOT NULL,
    [winner] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [wire ID] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [incumbent] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [order] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [projected winner] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RACE_CANDIDATES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [race number] ASC,
    [candidate num] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[RACE]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RACE](
    [race number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [sum results] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [fix percents] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [winners] [smallint] NULL,
    [maximum vote] [int] NOT NULL,
    [default cg] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [title1] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [title2] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [title3] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [talent1] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [talent2] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [talent3] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [wire id1] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [wire id2] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [total precincts] [int] NOT NULL,
    [precincts reporting] [int] NULL,
    [last update] [int] NULL,
    [last update producer] [int] NULL,
    [last air] [int] NULL,
    [last lead change] [int] NULL,
    [last winner change] [int] NULL,
    [total vote] [int] NULL,
    [change vote] [int] NULL,
    [report_to_1] [int] NULL,
    [report_to_2] [int] NULL,
    [report_to_3] [int] NULL,
    [other1] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [other2] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [other3] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [other4] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [winners selected] [smallint] NULL,
    [max probable] [smallint] NULL,
    [precinct percent] [smallint] NULL,
    [yesno1] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [yesno2] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [yesno3] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [yesno4] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [autowin precinct] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [autowin both] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [wire winner] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [leader] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [leader percent] [smallint] NULL,
    [leader2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [leader2 percent] [smallint] NULL,
    [sort by party] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [airable] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [reports from] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RACE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [race number] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[CANDIDATE]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CANDIDATE](
    [candidate number] [int] IDENTITY(5000,1) NOT NULL,
    [party] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [first name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [last name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [initial] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [talent] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [cother1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [cother2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [cother3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [logo] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CANDIDATE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [candidate number] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_sum results]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_sum results]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [sum results]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_fix percents]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_fix percents]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [fix percents]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_winners]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_winners]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [winners]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_maximum vote]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_maximum vote]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [maximum vote]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_default cg]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_default cg]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [default cg]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_title1]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_title1]  DEFAULT (N'<New Race>') FOR [title1]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_total precincts]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_total precincts]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [total precincts]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_precincts reporting]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_precincts reporting]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [precincts reporting]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_last update]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_last update]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [last update]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_last update producer]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_last update producer]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [last update producer]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_last air]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_last air]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [last air]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_last lead change]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_last lead change]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [last lead change]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_last winner change]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_last winner change]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [last winner change]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_total vote]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_total vote]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [total vote]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_change vote]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_change vote]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [change vote]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_report_to_1]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_report_to_1]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [report_to_1]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_report_to_2]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_report_to_2]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [report_to_2]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_report_to_3]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_report_to_3]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [report_to_3]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_winners selected]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_winners selected]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [winners selected]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_max probable]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_max probable]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [max probable]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_precinct percent]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_precinct percent]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [precinct percent]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_yesno1]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_yesno1]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [yesno1]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_yesno2]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_yesno2]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [yesno2]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_yesno3]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_yesno3]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [yesno3]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_yesno4]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_yesno4]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [yesno4]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_autowin precinct]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_autowin precinct]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [autowin precinct]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_autowin both]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_autowin both]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [autowin both]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_wire winner]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_wire winner]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [wire winner]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_leader percent]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_leader percent]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [leader percent]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_leader2 percent]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_leader2 percent]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [leader2 percent]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_sort by party]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_sort by party]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [sort by party]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_airable]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_airable]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [airable]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_RACE_reports from]    Script Date: 02/03/2014 08:55:03 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RACE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RACE_reports from]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [reports from]
GO
```

Please let me know if what I want to accomplish is even possible. Through coding...I know just about anything is possible. And I hope I asked the question properly. Thank you all for taking a gander at this.

**EDIT**:

I am able to join the two tables like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.[RACE CANDIDATES] 
JOIN [CANDIDATE] ON [RACE CANDIDATES].[candidate num] = [CANDIDATE].[candidate number]
```

Comment: Does `[dbo].[CANDIDATE].[candidate number]` relate to `[dbo].[RACE CANDIDATES].[candidate num]`? Also, I would not recommend spaces in SQL object names.

Comment: Yes, candidate numer and candidate num relate. Please see my edited question. About the spaces, I did not design the database, it's what I have to work with. What a pain ugh.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way

```
SELECT title1
   ,[precinct percent] AS [PrecinctPercent]
   ,leader
   ,[leader percent] AS [LeaderPercent]
   ,Winner
   ,WinningVotes
   ,c1.[Party]
   ,leader2
   ,[leader2 percent] AS [Leader2Percent]
   ,Loser
   ,LosingVotes
   ,c2.[Party]
FROM dbo.[RACE] r
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[CANDIDATE] AS c1
ON rc.Winner = c1.[candidate number]
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[CANDIDATE] AS c2
ON rc.Loser = c2.[candidate number]
INNER JOIN ( SELECT rc.[race number]
                   ,MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN [candidate num]
                        END) AS Winner
                   ,MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN Votes
                        END) AS WinningVotes
                   ,MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN [candidate num]
                        END) AS Loser
                   ,MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN Votes
                        END) AS LosingVotes
                FROM ( SELECT rc.*
                           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY rc.[race number] ORDER BY votes DESC ) AS seqnum
                        FROM dbo.[RACE CANDIDATES] rc ) rc
                GROUP BY rc.[race number] ) rc
    ON r.[race number] = rc.[race number]
FOR XML PATH('WQAD')
       ,ROOT('root')
```

your best alternative would be to return all candidate data including `PARTY` before trying to do other functions on it.

Comment: This one above is giving me invalid column names for Winner and Loser.  I will work with it and use your advice to see if I can get the desired results. Thank you for you input!

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake Winner and Loser should be coming from `rc` tag not from `r` try again.

Comment: The multi-part identifier "rc.Winner" could not be bound. Same with "rc.Loser"

Comment: than just try `Winner` and `Loser`

Comment: That calls back the "invalid column names" hmmm. We'll get it figured out.

Comment: I think the problem comes from inside and outside Select using `rc` alias. try to rename one of it to something else.

Comment: Would anyone like to take a stab at this? I got side tracked from the project at work today, but am now at home....hard at work once again. Thank you Everyone for helping out.